# select multiple columns containing specific value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a large table, of which I selected some rows whose id in (321,900,123)

```
id | col1 | col2 | col3
-----------------------
321| 1    |  0    | 0
900| 0    |  0    | 0
123| 0    |  0    | 1
```

I want to return 
col1 and col3 because they contain 1. How? 
I am doing a slow way of applying union on select statements. There must be a better way. I could have more columns in the future, so this hardcoding is not good.

```
    select col1 from table where id in (321,900,123) and col1=1 
union select col2 from table where id in (321,900,123) and col2=1 
union select col3 from table where id in (321,900,123) and col3=1
```

Comment: Have you tried to concatenate command as string and `EXEC (@command)`?

Comment: so I'll use this same command?

Comment: @waterling - Can you tell me if this is just a toy project or is it from some company database ? I wonder why someone would want to make such a query. Btw, why do you think this is slow ?

Comment: I'm just trying to set up some permissions. this table tells me if the id has permission to each col :) it's slow because you are executing separate select statements and combining the results instead of executing one?

Comment: What output do you want from your query? The query you have provided will either have zero rows or one row with one column named `col1` that contains a `1`. There is no other results possible from that query regardless of what data you put in your table. I don't think that is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

One way to approach this, seeing as they are numeric values, is to sum the two columns:

```
select col1+col3 as selected
  from tab
where id in (321,900,123)
 and col1+col3>=1
```

But this does have some assumptions built in. Depending on your requirements, it may work for you. [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/76df4/5). (Pity sql server does not allow column aliases in a `where` clause as it would have read better as `and selected>=1`.)

Another way would be to do something like:

```
select 1 
from tab
where id in (321,900,123)
  and ( col1=1
    or col3=1 )
```

But again depends on your exact requirements